# Redistribute modified Ubuntu Server for Raspberry Pi

Tags: server, lts, license

i developed a small control for electronic inside houses. Because it's very difficult for some users to install the fully software on their own i did everything (setup, configuration etc.) on my raspberry pi and took an image from that. This image now includes Ubuntu Server 20.04.1 LTS for Raspberry Pi 3 and my installed software (which is openSource on Github). I'd like to make it downloadable on my homepage.

Is this possible or do i get in conflict with a license from ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redistribute a modified Ubuntu. However, you must be VERY clear that it is NOT stock Ubuntu. Lots of respins are "Based on Ubuntu."

The bigger problem you have with a respin of Ubuntu is ongoing support. Your respin may not be compatible with future Ubuntu security patches and bugfixes, and you will need to remake the respin for future releases of Ubuntu. You (not us) will be responsible for providing ALL support, even to the parts you didn't modify. (We will close any support question unanswered if it's not stock Ubuntu)

Instead of a respin of the entire OS, consider distributing the software as a deb or a snap (or both).

- If you distribute using the existing deb/snap channels, you don't need to maintain your own download page. You get the full power of the Debian Archives, the Ubuntu Mirrors, and the Snap Store.
- Your support burden is reduced: AskUbuntu and other Ubuntu support venues will provide general OS support for your users.
- Your users are secure: The Ubuntu Security Team will distribute patches to keep your users' OS secure.
- Your codebase is much smaller, since you only maintain *your* code.

Snaps have two additional features that are very attractive for IOT devices:

- Built-in auto-updates. You don't have the support burden of old versions still floating around. This also means assured distribution of security patches.
- Compatible with Ubuntu Core, which is snap-only, secure, and has worked on RPIs for years. Core is designed for autonomous and semi-autonomous appliances; users don't need to admin or maintain them.

Comment: hey @user5335733 and thanks for this very clear answer! I already thought about a deb but i'm not able to get this running (have to read further and deeper into that). I'm just checking licensing from mongoDB right now because i also preinstalled it inside my image. nodejs, mongodb and lighttpd are installed.